# Error in sum$adjr2 : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Tags: r, excel, iphone, model

I met the error when doing this code below:

```
models <- order(sum$adjr2, decreasing = T)[1:3]
Error in sum$adjr2 : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable
```

Please help me fix it, thank you so much!

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: i figured it out, I should add step.search.summ$adjr2 instead of sum$adjr2
#which variables were used in each of the combination
step.search.summ$which